# Как убрать текст после изменение с помочью bot.edit_message_text TeleBot

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot, inline

После нажатии кнопки назад в меню редактируется инлайн кнопки, кроме предыдущее сообщение. Остаётся сообщение "Предметы"

```
from telebot import types
from bg import keep_alive
bot = telebot.TeleBot('TOKEN')

@bot.message_handler(commands = ['start'])
def get_user_info(message):
    markup_inline = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
    btn1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='TEXT', callback_data='nam')
    btn2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='TEXT', callback_data='nenam')
    markup_inline.add(btn1, btn2)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'TEXT',reply_markup = markup_inline)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func = lambda call: True)
def callback(call):
    if call.data == 'nenam':
        markup_inline = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
        alg2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='TEXT', callback_data='u')
        uu = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='TEXT', callback_data='u1')
        mar2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='TEXT', callback_data='back')
        markup_inline.add(alg2,uu )
        markup_inline.row(mar2)
        bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.id, text='Предметы',
                          reply_markup=markup_inline)
    if call.data == 'u':
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'TEXT')
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'TEXT')
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'TEXT')
    if call.data == 'u1':
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'TEXT')
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'TEXT')
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'TEXT')
    elif call.data == 'back':
        bot.edit_message_text(call.message.text, call.message.chat.id, call.message.message_id, reply_markup=get_user_info(call.message))
```

Comment: Текст в `editmessagetext` в данном случае можно убрать, просто оставив пустое сообщение.

Comment: ну он не возвращает обратно